# The search console has thrown a new error which is affecting 95 pages of my site

Tags: google-search-console, google-console-developer, razorpay

The error shown is "These hosts serve site resources that are blocked to Googlebot. If Googlebot can't access important resources on your page, the page might be indexed incorrectly. "
The hostname is https://checkout.razorpay.com

Comment: you havent asked a question. What do you want?

Comment: i want to know why is it happening and how can I resolve it.